# How to fix EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

I want to create a calendar entry to the iPhone calendar, I have tried the following code

```
        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title     = self.selectedPost.postTitle;
        event.notes     = self.selectedPost.postContent;
        event.startDate =  self.selectedPost.startDate;
        event.endDate   =  self.selectedPost.endDate;

        EKCalendar *targetCalendar = nil;
        targetCalendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        NSLog(@"%@",targetCalendar);
        [event setCalendar:targetCalendar];
        NSError *err;
        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        UIAlertView *alert = nil;
        NSLog(@"err %@",err);
        if (err) {
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[err localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        }
        else{
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Added to calender" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        }

        [alert show];
```

but result is

```
2013-01-15 22:31:34.682 Project[40863:907] defaultCalendarForNewEvents failed: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"
2013-01-15 22:31:34.683 Project[40863:907] (null)
2013-01-15 22:31:34.690 Project[40863:907] err Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x1d535ba0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}
```

I know this is because of

```
[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
```

returns null.
I have tried 
 [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:event.calendarItemIdentifier];
and some other code but same result how to fix this
Any idea

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am already making the request to access user's calendar using the method given in accepted answer. I am getting defaultCalendarForNewEvents as nil, even after I instantiate it again inside the completion block. Any idea?

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb which entity type (`EKEntityType`) you are passing?

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb if you are passing `EKEntityTypeReminder` the `defaultCalendarForNewEvents ` will be nil. then you should use `-[EKEventStore  defaultCalendarForNewReminders]`

Comment: I was passing EKEntityTypeEvent. It got fixed. I checked the calendar app and there was no calendar to select from (iOS bug I think). When I restarted the phone, the list got populated and the error fixed itself. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is on iOS 6.0 or later, you'll have to first request access to the user's calendars before EventKit will hand them to you by using the method [-[EKEventStore requestAccessToEntityType:completion:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)

Check out the example given in the [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of not-wasting-your-time just make sure, that you are using the bit masks in [-[EKEventStore requestAccessToEntityType:completion:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/requestAccessToEntityType%3acompletion%3a)

like this

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityMaskEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making sure that the title wasn't the same as the one that i was creating, for example I have `dance` on several nights so for one night i would do `Dance` and the other one with a period at the beginning `.Dance`.

Answer (score 0):

Add those lines

```
if(eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents==nil)
*eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

Second line will execute only first time when you grant access

Your code should look like this below

```
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title     = self.selectedPost.postTitle;
    event.notes     = self.selectedPost.postContent;
    event.startDate =  self.selectedPost.startDate;
    event.endDate   =  self.selectedPost.endDate;

    EKCalendar *targetCalendar = nil;
   if(eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents==nil)
      *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    targetCalendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    NSLog(@"%@",targetCalendar);
    [event setCalendar:targetCalendar];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
    UIAlertView *alert = nil;
    NSLog(@"err %@",err);
    if (err) {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[err localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    }
    else{
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Added to calender" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    }

    [alert show];
```

this works for me

Comment: i write this line:    if(self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents==nil)
        *self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
Then show error Assigning to Eveventstore from incompatible type Ekeventatore

Comment: What is that selectedPost,that is an error in my code,please explain it.